# Como calcular o índice de McLoone?

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma base de dados *uniao* onde preciso realizar a seguinte operação com a coluna VAA, desagregada por estados (UF):

Dividir o somatório de todas as observações abaixo da mediana, pela mediana multiplicada pelo número de observações abaixo da mediana.

Eu apenas consegui calcular a mediana desagregada por estados, através do seguinte código:

```
median <- aggregate(x=uniao$VAA, by=list (uniao$UF.x), FUN=median)
```

Depois, não consegui proseguir. Segue uma amostra da base. Desde já, agradeço.

```
~Cod.IBGE, ~UF.x, ~GastoMunEduc2017,             ~Municipio,          ~VAA,
2926657L,  "BA",               293,    "RIBEIRAO DO LARGO", "0,112045889",
2708501L,  "AL",           5262048, "SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE", "71,44668024",
3141108L,  "MG",         118502319,           "MATOZINHOS", "351,9522394",
1503309L,  "PA",        1265213922,         "IGARAPE-MIRI", "739,8046556",
2103802L,  "MA",         425038332,            "DOM PEDRO", "899,7424471",
2708105L,  "AL",         524661607,    "SANTANA DO MUNDAU", "2000,234872",
2807303L,  "SE",         117161813,                "TELHA", "2099,674068",
2407500L,  "RN",         598046562,         "MAXARANGUAPE", "2202,749768",
4303301L,  "RS",          82870338,              "CAIBATE", "2233,701833",
2108603L,  "MA",        4369992772,             "PINHEIRO", "2386,670001",
1304104L,  "AM",         960827383,               "TAPAUA", "2420,220108",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para começar, a coluna `VAA` está entre aspas e portanto é lida como `"character"`, é preciso primeiro transformar em `"numeric"`.

```
uniao$VAA <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", uniao$VAA))
```

Para agregar a coluna `VAA` por `UF.x` pode-se usar a interface de fórmula.

```
aggregate(VAA ~ UF.x, uniao, median)
```

Mas não é necessário calcular este resultado para obter o valor descrito na pergunta.

```
fun <- function(x){
  med <- median(x)
  mean(x[x < med])/med
}

fun(uniao$VAA)
#[1] 0.2062816
```

Se quiser agregar os dados aplicando esta função, poderá ser com uma instrução muito semelhante à de cima, basta mudar de `median` para `fun`.

```
aggregate(VAA ~ UF.x, uniao, fun)
```